# Listening to Collapsing toolbar scrim change

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I've a collapsing toolbar with scrim color as my app's primary color.
That's working as expected. 
Now I want to get a callback when collapsing toolbar applied scrim color where I want to change the color of title into white. I've tried onOffsetChangeListener. But I need to know at which point scrim color is being applied.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? [ask] with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is to add

```
app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/MyCollapsedTextAppearance"
```

to your

```
android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

This will do what you need **and** make it adhere to normal material design

Answer (score 0):

Use *setCollapsedTitleTextColor()* method to achieve this.

```
mCollapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.white);
```